# How can I distinguish the n-th matched pattern of the m-th capture group of a regular expression from earlier or later matches in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, date, iso8601, capture-group

This question pertains to regular expressions that can be processed by bash.

I have a regular expression which finds in a text all matches of a date in the notation d.m.yyyy or dd.m.yyyy or d.mm.yyyy or dd.mm.yyyy if it happens to be between tabs or at least two white spaces:

`(?<=\t|\s{2,})(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4})(?=\t|\s{2,})`

**How can I replace all the findings of this** (let's assume first) **capture group by a date formatted according to ISO 8601**, i.e. in the notation yyyy-mm-dd?

Since the delimiting tabs or t least double spaces are in a lookaround condition they do not belong to my capture group. They would remain as they were in the original string.

The problem decomposes to:

**1. how to address the n-th match of $1**

**2. how do I rearrange the three components separated by dots in this case?**

Comment: It is my understanding that regular expressions in bash do not support lookaround. Are you looking for a solution in pure bash, or using a program (such as `sed` or `perl`) to perform this transformation?

Comment: Bash uses POSIX Extended Regular Expressions, which do not understand constructs like `\d` or `(?...)`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is contradictory in itself.

Comment: Occasionally I use regular expressions from Mathematica and they can definitely do lookaround conditions. However, they unfortunately do not provide an example for capture groups. - At least thanks for the one answer below, that helped already, because I'm not a regex expert, but one who is just learning it. And for that, the answer below is more inspiring than the comments above. Thanks, tsiono!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to process it with `bash`, would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

str=$'foo\t27.6.2021  bar'                      # example of the input line
pat=$'^(.*)(\t| {2,})([0-9]{1,2})\.([0-9]{1,2})\.([0-9]{4})(\t| {2,})(.*)$'
if [[ $str =~ $pat ]]; then
    a=("${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}")                  # assign array "a" to the matched substrings excluding "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}" (entire match)
    y=${a[4]}; a[4]=${a[2]}; a[2]=$y;           # swap year and date
    printf "%s%s%04d-%02d-%02d%s%s\n" "${a[@]}" # print the formatted result
fi
```

As commented, bash regex does not support lookarounds. You need to capture whole line as substrings and reuse them.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful since it explains the single steps, which you have provided after noticing right, that is was a naive non-expert's question. Thank you very much not only providing a solution but a really concise tutorial, not leaving out the remark on the non-existence of lookaround conditions in bash - I did not know that before!

Comment: Thank you for your polite feedback. Good to know my answer worked.